# How to refactor for template variations & shared methods

Tags: design-patterns, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

We have a few different ways of rendering a post (e.g., full page, modal view, collapsed view, edit mode, etc.) Many methods are shared between them. We keep all of these variations as templates inside `Post.vue` and pass on a context prop to render a certain one conditionally using `v-if`:

```
<single-post
  :post="currPost"
  :canEditPost="canEditPost"
  :targetPageUrl="targetPageUrl"
  :mailToLink="mailToLink"
  :onAddComment="addComment"
  :onDeleteComment="deleteComment"
  :onShowMoreComments="showMoreComments"
  :onShowFewerComments="showFewerComments"
  :onGoToPost="goToPost"
  v-if="context === 'feed'"
/>

<post-full
  :post="currPost"
  :canEditPost="canEditPost"
  :targetPageUrl="targetPageUrl"
  :mailToLink="mailToLink"
  :postImage="postImage"
  :units="units"
  :divisionsByType="divisionsByType"
  v-if="context === 'permalink'"
/>

(many more versions)
```

Then there are methods in the `Post.vue` like this one:

```
deletePost: function(){
  BootBox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this post?", (confirmed) => {
    if (confirmed) {
      API.deletePost(this.currPost, (err) => {
        if (!err){
          this.currPost.status = 'deleted';
        }
      });
    }
  });
},
```

How can I refactor this to be more elegant and less verbose?

To me it this seems super verbose (way too many props). I've been looking for vue or vuex patterns for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `v-bind` is your friend here, and `<component>`, with a `PostModel`

Create a `PostModel` that predefines all the functions and properties of your re-usable post:

```
export default {
    post: {},
    canEditPost: function() {},
    targetPageUrl: '',
    //...
}
```

Then import your `SinglePost` (or whichever you need) along with the `PostModel`

```
import SinglePost from '/path/to/SinglePost';
import PostModel from './path/to/PostModel';

export default {

    data() {
        return {
            thePostComponent: SinglePost,
            postProps: Object.assign({}, PostModel, {
                post: post,
                canEditPost: canEditPost,
                targetPageUrl: targetPageUrl
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea above is that you're overwriting the object with any custom configurations for a given post, but you don't need to continuously define the properties on the component its self, creating a more self-contained and reusable component. If you're passing these properties in from, say, an API, you could even more easily integrate this to make this more flat and reusable by using the `Interceptor` pattern to map your model to the API.

And finally, dynamically display that component:

```
For a reusable component:

<component :is="thePostComponent" v-bind="postProps">
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: +1 makes a ton of sense. Only thing, isn't this going outside the vue pattern to create a PostModel.js file and new model folder?

Comment: @Kyle You could definitely say that, I'm not claiming to be an expert by any means but I find this method to be useful

Comment: I'm down to use it this way. Looks great to me. Just wanted to know if I should be drawing inside the lines while I get my head around vue... but answer accepted and thanks for your help